# Multiple transactions with same nonce, pending ones makes me crazy rest is ok, but why?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, gas, gas-price

I am playing with smart contracts in code, sending/receiving transactions to/from it. Some transactions with lower `gasPrice` are stuck in a pending state. However, having same nonce with a higher `gasPrice` passed. Pending ones still pending and seems to be pending forever. How can I clear those or when will they discard, is there an amount of time to wait them to be discarded?

Answer (score 1):

If a transaction with the same nonce has already been broadcast, then the others will be cleared from the tx pool.

This is a rule set by the clients that run nodes.

Comment: ok but when will this clearance process complete since the time last transaction occured with the same nonce? is there any amount of time?